# jQuery ui clone main draggable and make cloned draggable as well

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 draggable elements `X` and `O` on the top of the page, beneath them there is a 3x3 droppable grid. I want to be able to clone `X` or `O` to one of the grid cells and be able to drag that cloned element to other grid cells.

For example, when I drag `X` to the top left cell it should be cloned to that cell and I would still drag that cloned element to the second cell or any other cell.

Something like that:

```
__________________________________________________________
|                      X      O                          |
|________________________________________________________|

After dragging X:
_____________________
|  X  |      |      |
|_____|______|______|
|     |      |      |
|_____|______|______|
|     |      |      |
|_____|______|______|

After moving X to 2nd cell
____________________
|     |  X   |      |
|_____|______|______|
|     |      |      |
|_____|______|______|
|     |      |      |
|_____|______|______|
```

Here is a live fiddle to make changes and test: https://jsfiddle.net/2qatpe47/

CSS:

```
.header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.drag{
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.zone{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.drop{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-droppable-disabled {
    background: #494f54;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <span class="drag main">X</span>
  <span class="drag main">O</span>
</div>
<div class="zone">
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop disabled"></div> <!-- Droppable Disabled -->
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});


$(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".drag",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        //If the dragged element is `X` or `O` on the top
        if($(ui.draggable).hasClass('main')){
            var cloned = $(ui.draggable).clone();
          
            cloned.removeClass('main');

            $(this).append(cloned);

            //cloned.draggable();
        }
        
        $(this).droppable('disable');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).droppable('enable');
    }
});

//Disable Droppable for elements with .disabled
$('.disabled').droppable('disable');
```

The issue is that I can't drag the cloned element after dropping it. I tried to add this `cloned.draggable();` it's commented out to make that cloned element draggable but the issue is that I can drag it anywhere including disabled droppable and to other cells which already contain cloned elements and the cell with the element dragged out is disabled.

I want each cell to contain only one dragged element and if I move the element to another cell it shouldn't be disabled.

Comment: In your `drop` event, you should append the item and then initialize draggable to it.

Comment: @TwistyI tried that you can see this line is commented `cloned.draggable();` but the issue is that I can drag the cloned element everywhere even disabled droppables

Comment: That does not append the element to new drop location. The other part is how you initialize both the drag and the drop.

Comment: @Twisty Do you mean after cloning the element? I tried to run the droppable function again after cloning and dropping but it didn't work. If you have a working example you tried please share it

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".header .drag").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $(".zone .drag").draggable({
    containment: ".zone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".drag",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dropped;
      if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('main')) {
        dropped = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        dropped.removeClass('main');
      } else {
        dropped = ui.draggable;
      }
      dropped.appendTo(this).draggable({
        containment: ".zone",
        revert: "invalid"
      });
      dropped.css({
        top: '',
        left: ''
      });
      $(".zone .drop").filter(function(i, el) {
        return $(".drag", el).length !== 1;
      }).droppable("enable");
      $(this).droppable("disable");
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).droppable('enable');
    }
  });

  //Disable Droppable for elements with .disabled
  $('.disabled').droppable('disable');
});
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.drag {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.zone {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.drop {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-droppable-disabled {
  background: #494f54;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="header">
  <span class="drag main">X</span>
  <span class="drag main">O</span>
</div>
<div class="zone">
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop disabled">
    <span class="drag">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
</div>
```

By default, a Cloned element does not retain Data and Events. So we need to re-initialize Draggable after it's been appended to the Drop element.